# e-democracy: web based voting software

Tags: web-applications, voting

For an organization counting a few thousands of members, can you recommend web based voting software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [Google Moderator](http://moderator.appspot.com/) (which will require each one to have an Google acount) or [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/) (which SO uses to rank feature requests).

Comment: The link to Google Moderator seems to be broken now.